# Git does not add all my files

Tags: git, github

I've created a project a while ago and switched computers in between. I cloned my project and am pushing/building from my new computer now.

Everything I change is added and pushed perfectly fine (with `git commit -am`). But I've discovered that I've added some files to my local project whom aren't being pushed to my github.

A LOT of files. Now; Using `git add *` says `fatal: no files added`.

Any ideas how I can push my entire project to github now and being able to use it properly again? I'm totally lost in Git world :)

Comment: what is the output of git status?

Comment: Pretty much all the files I've added to my local project recently. Including the ones in my ignore.

Comment: do they appear under "files to be commited"? or untracked files?

Comment: Apparantly `git add --all` works after trying that 3x. Thanks for your help either way :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `git add --all`, it adds EVERYTHING. Then you can remove those files that you don't want to commit.

Comment: Ok, I swear that didn't work when I tried it 15 minutes ago. Did now though. Instead of `git commit` what should I type? I got this weird console thingie where I had to write a .commitmsg or something and use ctrl+x to leave.

Comment: When you invoke `git commit` it opens your default editor, normally that is emacs or vi but you can set it to anything. If you don't want that editor you can also add a message with `git commit -m'the message goes here'`